# No more sound on a Lenovo y50-70 with linux Mint 18.3

Tags: linux, linux-mint, drivers, audio

Every time I've installed any version of Linux on my laptop, I used to have sound only from two speakers and my sub-woofer for some reason was not working. I've decided to change that and learn the way how to solve that problem. Unfortunately by making changes and trying to fix that, I've messed up much more. Now I have totally no sound and my Linux can't even recognize audio hardware. I was following some steps on one forum (can't find that post now), where in one of the last steps, I had to change pins by overriding them, and that was the step where everything messed up, and I can't reverse that. I was trying literally everything I could found on the web (pulseaudio, rejacking once again), and for some reason I can't fix it. Is there any way I can restore default audio settings for Linux? Is there any normal and working way that can make my audio work again (and properly this time)? I'm currently using Mint Sylvia 18.3 on a Lenovo y50-70.

PS1. Sound is working great on Windows 10.

PS2. I don't really want to reinstall my Linux right now, since I have a lot of data here and I'm working a lot on Linux (and even if I would do a reinstall, I would still not have sound from the sub-woofer).

PS3. I was trying all the solutions I've found on many pages, including a lot of solved questions here on this forum :)

Comment: This is a not-proper way to ask for a question! You must provide as more as information you can (e.g. post followed to try fixing the sub-woofer issue), as well as write it grammatically corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know that much about audio settings and drivers, if you're only worried about your data and that's what's keeping you from reinstalling your Mint, couldn't you back it up on an external HDD or a USB stick and just `chown -R 754 your-directory-in-the-external-device` (so that they aren't locked and you can read them with your user in the next installation / other devices)?

EDIT: The parameters on `chown` from `777` to `754` + added some clarification. Also, please view the comment thread under this comment for an alternative way of doing this with `tar` and `cpio`!

Comment: `chown -R 777` blindly is not good practice. Moreover this operation may not be supported in the first place if the external storage has not been formatted as `ext`. The point of making a back up and reinstall is OK, but the OP explicitly states that he does not want a reinstall for reasons more than "having a lot of data".

Comment: Good point about him now wanting to reinstall, but since OP made quite a few changes to his config and doesn't know exactly what was done, maybe it would be best to do a reset. As for the blind `777`, it should only be temporary, just until the new user on his new install can use `chown` to control read/write functionality on the files.

Comment: You may `tar` your files and save that instead as a backup. That would preserve most of the information including permissions and can be stored on a non-ext3/4 partition keeping the most of the information. Another option is `cpio`.

Comment: Very good point, my first intuition with `chmod` was because I had some issues with ownership of the files and transferring them from one install to another. E.g an HDD from my main desktop with backups couldn't be read by my rPi FTP server. Woouldn't OP have similar issues if the files just get `tar`-ed?

Comment: You may wish to check the issue manually instead of blindly changing all of them to `777`, even if you want to change the permission `chmod -R -X` is much better since it automatically decides which files need the `x` permission and which do not. My point in the last sentence is use `X` instead of `x`.

Comment: You're right, just thought of another alternative: using `chmod 754`, so that on the next installation / other device, you can at least read the files and potentially make edit-able copies of them.

Comment: You can kind of sort out the information in the comments and edit them into your answer. Also welcome to U&L SE!

Comment: Will edit my answer accordingly, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no a magic command which can take care of **yourself-made** problem.

Probably the most easy solution for you is to reinstall the entire system.
Or erase your *$HOME* with the hope to reset your DE settings.

All depends on what changes you have made on your system.